# Querying Datetime Objects In Python & Comparing With Current Date

Tags: python, datetime, sqlite

I have this piece of code that I want to print something when the current date is greater than the date in the SQLite3 table.

```
import sqlite3
from datetime import *

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("CREATE TABLE mutes (name text, seconds int)")
conn.commit()

c.execute("INSERT INTO mutes VALUES (:name, :seconds)", {"name": "William", "seconds": 60})
conn.commit()

while True:
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM mutes WHERE name=:name", {"name":"William"})
    now = datetime.now()
    togo = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=int(c.fetchone()[1]))
    if now >= togo:
        print("Release!!!")
        break
```

I know it sort of works as when I inverse the condition on the if statement, it prints out also. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you were to subtract time or not add time, `datetime.now()` will never be greater than or equal to `datetime.now() + x`

In this case, you are adding 60 seconds to `datetime.now()` and then asking if `datetime.now()` is greater than or equal to `datetime.now() + 60 seconds`.  It isn't possible.

If your intent is to print when the current date is greater than your test date, you need to have a test date of *minus* 60 seconds.

```
import sqlite3
from datetime import *

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("CREATE TABLE mutes (name text, seconds int)")
conn.commit()

c.execute("INSERT INTO mutes VALUES (:name, :seconds)", {"name": "William", "seconds": 60})
conn.commit()

while True:
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM mutes WHERE name=:name", {"name":"William"})
    now = datetime.now()
    togo = datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=int(c.fetchone()[1]))
    if now >= togo:
        print("Release!!!")
        break
```

If you want `while True` to run for 60 seconds before you get the `break` and `print` then you could change to this:
    import sqlite3
    from datetime import *

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("CREATE TABLE mutes (name text, seconds int)")
conn.commit()

c.execute("INSERT INTO mutes VALUES (:name, :seconds)", {"name": "William", "seconds": 60})
conn.commit()

c.execute("SELECT * FROM mutes WHERE name=:name", {"name":"William"})
togo = datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=int(c.fetchone()[1]))

while True:
    now = datetime.now()
    if now >= togo:
        print("Release!!!")
        break
```

Comment: So how could I make this work? Because logically it would be. If the first time was `2018-10-30 10:34:54.257985` and that started counting - it would come to `2018-10-30 10:35:54.257985`.

Comment: Right now you are doing
`2018-10-30 10:34:54.257985 = now` and `2018-10-30 10:35:54.257985 = togo` and then testing `if now >= togo`.  It isn't.  And every time you loop, now and togo get reset to the same amount of extra time that it takes to loop.  You could initiate `now` outside of `while True` and then after 60 seconds of your while loop running, you would get the `print("Release")`.

Comment: You have just made me hit myself for forgetting that. Thank you!

Comment: I actually made a mistake, the now() needs to update since it is moving forward so it should be inside the `while` and `togo` should be initiated outside of the `while` loop.  My previous comment said the opposite.  I edited my answer above.